# there is a white space (margin) below the fullscreen revolution slider (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, whitespace, margin

Here is my site: http://highcatering.wpengine.com/
When you make the browser width smaller, a white space appears below the top revolution slider.

I don't know how to eliminate it.

I have tried:

```
.boxedWrap .fullScreenSlider {height: 100%;}
.boxedWrap .fullScreenSlider {position: absolute;}
```

Doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
height: auto;
```

I'm guessing that it's inside this html element.

```
<div class="sliderHomeBullets slider_engine_revo slider_alias_homeslide" style="display: block; height: auto;">
```

**Display bug (before) :**

[image: Display bug]

**Corrected bug (after) :**

[image: Corrected bug]

Hope this help you.

PS: Nice pictures :)

Comment: Thanks @s0h3ck! Where do I put the code? Directly on the stylesheet? What exact code do I put in the stylesheet?
D:
Bit confused... :D

Comment: Put this "height: auto;" in the stylesheet and it should work.

Comment: Did you try to put it inside the div element? or I'm guessing you didn't put the css property to the right place.

Comment: You where right, @sOh3ck. The theme creators finally answered me and they added the following code to the stylesheet: .sliderHomeBullets{height; auto!important;}

The !important was missing, I guess, because I tried that statement before(without the !important).